# How can I promisify this function so it does not hold up my server from starting up?

Tags: javascript, time, promise

I want it to complete when it has found a minute.  So obviously it may take up to a minute:

```
function syncToMinute(){
  let proceed = true;
  while(proceed){
    const date = new Date();
    let seconds = date.getSeconds();
    if( seconds === 0){
      console.log('Minute Found');
      proceed = false;
    } else {
      // console.log(seconds);
    }
  }
}
```

Usage would be:

```
syncToMinute().then(() => {
  anotherFunc();
})
```

Comment: Does this have a good purpose? What about milliseconds?

Comment: I don't need that level of accuracy yet.  I just need to know the simplest way to promisify this function.

Comment: What do you want to achieve with your function? Maybe there is a better way to do it. Do you want to run a function each minute?

Comment: Rather than checking constantly, why don't you check how far away you are from a minute, and then wait that long?

Comment: I doing a delta between my client time and my server time using the `new Date()` constructor on each.  I'm sure there are many ways to do it, but this is how my preference.

Comment: I want to know the exact moment new Date() hits a minute.  This was a question about how to promisify it not come up with another way to do it ... unless my way is impossible?

Comment: looks to me like the solution from Tomas does what is wanted, unless I am not understanding the requirements. on edit: oh no I can see you wanted to have an example where you use promise.then when the minute is over.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can calculate how many seconds remain till the next minute (a delta), then set a 
`setTimeout` that resolves a `Promise` in that delta.

```js
const syncToMinute = () => {
  const delta = 60 - (new Date()).getSeconds()
  
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, delta * 1000))
}

syncToMinute()
  .then(() => {
    console.log('Minute')
  })
```

For the record, a `while` loop; like you have in your OP, will always freeze up the event loop regardless if it's wrapped in a `Promise`. Wrapping something in a Promise doesn't make it run in a separate thread.

Comment: but when getSeconds returns 0 it would wait for a minute

Comment: @EvgenyTimoshenko I'm not going to cover edge cases; I've demonstrated the concept, the OP can adjust as necessary.

Comment: @Nik - so you are saying I can not promisify my function even if I wanted to?

Comment: @J.M. Sure you can but it would still freeze up the process.

Comment: Well then it would not do what a promise is supposed to do which is allow proceeding code to run and run the then() when the promise is completed and returned?

Comment: I never trusted the accuracy of setTimeout and setInterval.  But if this is all that will work I can switch methods.

Comment: J.M. Long-running code that doesn't deal with I/O freezes up the process regardless if it's wrapped in a Promise. I'm oversimplifying a bit here so you might wanna read up on the [Event Loop](https://nodejs.dev/the-nodejs-event-loop/) yourself.

Comment: ＋1 for mentioning that while loop cannot be promisified.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can, just calculate the difference in time between your time and required time:

```
/**
 * Waits until the local time has no second remainder.
 * @returns {Promise<void>}
 * */
function SyncToMinute() {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        const now = new Date();
        const secondsNow = now.getSeconds() + now.getMilliseconds()/1000;

        const secondsUntill00 = 60 - secondsNow;
        setTimeout(resolve, secondsUntill00*1000);
    });
}
```

Example:

```
(async () => {
    console.log("Start wait, time is: ", new Date());
    await SyncToMinute();
    console.log("Done waiting, time is: ", new Date());
})();
```

On my computer it logs:

```
Start wait, time is:  
Date Tue Dec 03 2019 15:30:36 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time)
debugger eval code:16:13
Done waiting, time is:  
Date Tue Dec 03 2019 15:31:00 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time)
```

But whatever you are doing is [probably something really wrong. This is not how servers should behave.

Answer (score 1):

```
const resolveTimeout = () => { 
 const seconds = 59 - new Date().getSeconds();
 return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, seconds * 1000));
}

resolveTimeout().then(() => { console.log('Minute found')});
```

Comment: Why do you use 59 and not 60? If the function is called at 12:00:00, your code will fire at 12:00:59, not 12:01:00...

Answer (score 0):

if you have async functions, you can do

```
async function syncToMinute() {
    const date = new Date();
    let seconds = date.getSeconds();
    if( seconds === 0){
      console.log('Minute Found');
      return true;
    } else {
      await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 1000)); // wait 1 second
      return await syncToMinute();
    }
}
```